# jquery function input radio onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, document-ready

Im trying to implement a self-written query function. A brief description about the function: It should recalculate two values when changing the radio button. It is working in JSFiddle. (http://jsfiddle.net/VL465/34/)

However now i'm trying to implement it in a real webpage. But actually i'm not able to get it working. I've tried to debug it but didn't grinder to a hold.

Currently the console is only showing the "Function loaded" message. When changing the radio buttons it doesn't display days recognized.

Let me clarify the current HTML file:

in the head i have:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/functions.js"></script>
```

The form is exactly the same:

```
<form action="/b/" method="POST" id="choseLessor">
    <fieldset>
    <input type="hidden" name="userLocale" value="en">
    <ul>
        <li><span class="rate"> € 21,29</span> <span class="note">starting at </span><span class="radio"></span><input type="radio" class="styled" name="days" value="30" data-price="21.29"><b>30 days </b></li>
        <li><span class="rate"> € 23,65</span> <span class="note">starting at </span><span class="radio" style="background-position: 0px -50px;"></span><input type="radio" class="styled" name="days" value="60" data-price="23.65" checked=""><b>60 days </b></li>
        <li><span class="rate"> € 26,02</span> <span class="note">starting at </span><span class="radio"></span><input type="radio" class="styled" name="days" value="90" data-price="26.02"><b>90 days </b></li>
        <li><span class="rate"> € 27,20</span> <span class="note">starting at </span><span class="radio"></span><input type="radio" class="styled" name="days" value="120" data-price="27.2"><b>120 days </b></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="priceCalculation">
        <div class="list">
            <span class="type">List Price:</span>
            <span class="retailPriceActual">
                <div class="strikethrough">€ 49,93</div>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="savings">
            <span class="type">Your Savings:</span>
            <span class="bookSavings" id="CalculateSavings">€ 26,28</span>
        </div>

        <div class="total">
            <span class="type bigger">Your Price:</span>
            <span class="totalPrice" id="CalculatePrice">€ 23,65</span>
        </div>

    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Cho" class="btn">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

And the contents of functions.js

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log ( 'Function loaded' );
    $("input[name=days]:radio").change(function () {  
        console.log ( 'Days recognized' );
        // get values
        var savingPrice = 0;
        var msrp = $('input[name="msrp"]').val();
        var periodPrice = $('input[name="days"]:checked').data('price');
        var userLocale = $('input[name="userLocale"]').val();

        console.log ( 'UserLocale' + userLocale);

        // calculate bac
            savingPrice = (msrp-periodPrice).toFixed(2); 

        if(userLocale === 'nl')
        {   
            savingPrice = savingPrice.replace(/\./g, ',');
            periodPrice = periodPrice.replace(/\./g, ',');
        }

        $('#CalculateSavings').text('&euro; ' + savingPrice);
        $('#CalculatePrice').text('&euro; ' + periodPrice);
    });
});
```

The console is showing:

```
Function loaded
```

And not more than this, even not when the radio button is changed.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You fiddle does not work. You cannot have a $(document).load inside an onload. This works: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/PXCrF/ - why the old jQuery btw? Also .text() does not work with entities

Comment: Have you tried moving your `script` elements to the bottom of the body, rather than putting them in the head?

Comment: If console shows function loaded then the script is obviously executed and does not need to be moved.
Peter: Are there more fields on the actual page, field perhaps with the same ID? Perhaps we need to see the URL

Comment: @Simon, moving the script down doesn't work either.

Comment: @mpungjan there are no other fields named days only the for in the above mentioned example. And both JSfiddle functions do actually work here. And for both the console only logs "function loaded."

Comment: I know the script is being executed, I just thought that perhaps the event was being bound after the page had rendered, and therefore wasn't being bound to these specific `input` elements. Perhaps using `$("input[name=days]:radio").on('change', function () {` would help?

Comment: @SimonAdcock thanks for your quick reply, this doesn't make any difference, still only function loaded is displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is not with your code per se, but how it interacts with the code contained with custom-form-elements.js

It seems that your radio buttons are hidden behind styled span elements, to improve the look and feel of the form. However, from a DOM perspective, the actual element that the user clicks on is not the radio button, but the span element.

The custom-form-elements script does some funky stuff behind the scenes to make it look like the radio button has been selected, but a `change` event is never fired on the radio button.

In order to get around this, you'll need to add something like the following to your `$(document).ready()`:

```
$("span.radio").click(function () { 
    $(this.nextSibling).trigger('change'); 
});
```

This will add a click event handler to the span masks that will fire the change event on their corresponding radio buttons. Looking at your HTML, `this.nextSibling` always refers to the radio button next to the span.

Comment: Hi, aaaaah that could be the case. But I'ts not perfectly clear to me what i have to change. I've tried the following: but is not working... http://jsfiddle.net/dtAAN/

Comment: You'll have to apply the changes to your actual website, rather than the Fiddle. The problem is with the way your code interacts with custom-form-elements.js on your website, which is not included in the JSFiddle mock-up.

Comment: @Peter perhaps a better solution would be to add the line `$(element.nextSibling).trigger('change');` to custom-form-elements.js, after `element.checked = true;` on line 118. Arguably the guy who wrote the script should have done something similar this in the first place, to allow you to define your own custom events on these buttons.

Comment: thanks for your help. I've tried the modify the custom-form-elements.js. However, i'm still experiencing trouble. This goes far beyond me knowledge. I really appreciate your! Can you help me in the last step..

Comment: Eeek, sorry, that's my bad! Change `$(element.nextSibling).trigger('change');` to just `$(element).trigger('change');` The variable `element` refers to the input button and so `trigger('change')` fires the `change` event that you defined above in your original question.

Comment: GREAT! You're my hero of the day, that works perfect! Thanks!

Comment: No problem, events can be very tricky to debug! Good work getting it going :)